# Looking for text books comparing animal and human brain

Tags: neuroscience

Are there any papers or textbooks comparing animal nervous system and human's ?
I'm most interested in "higher" animals such as mammals(Chimps, dogs etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what your looking for is a book on Comparative Neuroanatomy the only text book I could find in the field was:
[Comparative Vertebrate Neuroanatomy: Evolution and Adaptation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471210056) but you will find a number of web pages via google.

[Comparative Neuroanatomy](https://canvas.brown.edu/courses/851434/pages/comparative-neuroanatomy)